# Retention Policy with RMAN Incremental Backups

Tags: database, oracle, rman

I've configured RMAN Incremental Backups on my Oracle 11gR2 test database machine running on windows environment. I've set retention policy to recovery window of 7 days. On Sunday I take level zero incremental backup as follows:

```
run {
     HOST 'create_date_folder';
     allocate channel ch1 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_0LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     allocate channel ch2 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_0LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     allocate channel ch3 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_0LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 0 AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
     release channel ch1;
     release channel ch2;
     release channel ch3;
    }
```

On other week days I take level 1 cumulative incremental backup as follows:

```
run {
     HOST 'create_date_folder';
     allocate channel ch1 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_1LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     allocate channel ch2 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_1LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     allocate channel ch3 device type disk format 'F:\RMAN_BACKUPS\Database\%T\rman_1LVL_%d_s%s_p%p_t%t_%U';
     BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET CUMULATIVE DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;
     release channel ch1;
     release channel ch2;
     release channel ch3;
   }
```

**The problem** that I'm facing is that despite of setting retention policy old backups (of more than two weeks) are not being considered as obsolete/expired by RMAN as they are not removed by executing delete obsolete command. And, second question is that how to restrict RMAN to not remove Oracle generated Archivelogs. Pl guide.

Answer (score 0):

Could you print the content of SHOW ALL rman command please.

If you are you FRA, please execute select * from V$RECOVERY_FILE_DEST;

for you second question, it depends to what have you set for rman ARCHIVELOG DELETION POLICY configuration parameter and if you are using FRA or NO.